# Chrome 43 Flexbox flex-grow issue

Tags: flexbox, flex-grow

Before Chrome 43, div1 would take up 10% of the container height regardless of its childrens size, and div1 would overflow. As of Chrome 43 div1 doesnt follow flex-grow anyone more and instead grows to its childrens size. Is this supposed to work this way? How do i get div1 to overflow and follow its flex-grow property. Thanks!

Heres a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HorseFace/xsbmmf4o/

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="inner1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="inner2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    #container {
        height: 500px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #div1 {
        background: red;
        flex-grow: 0.1;
    }

    #inner1 {
        height: 200px;
        background: lightcoral;
    }

    #div2 {
        background: blue;
        flex-grow: 0.9;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #inner2 {
        height: 200px;
        background: #ccccff;
    }

    body {
        color: purple;
        background-color: #d8da3d
    }
```

Comment: try adding overflow:hidden to #div1

Comment: doesnt help unfortunatly.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/xcoths16/

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding [`flex-grow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-grow-property). It sets the [flex grow factor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-flex-grow-factor),

> which determines how much the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) will grow relative to the rest of the [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) in the flex container when positive free space is distributed. When omitted, it is set to `1`.

So only **free space** space is distributed. If you want that flex item to take up 10% of the flex container, you should set the [flex-basis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property) to `0`:

> the flex basis [is] the initial [main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size) of the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), before free space is distributed.

Note you can use the shorthand [`flex` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) to set both `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` simultaneously (and `flex-shrink` too):

```css
flex: 0.1; /*
  flex-grow: 0.1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
*/
```

Also note that the Flexbox spec changed the initial value of `min-height` and `min-width` to `auto` (previously it was `0`). This may break your percentages, so either use `overflow` different than `visible`, or set `min-height: 0`.

```css
body {
  color: purple;
  background-color: #d8da3d
}
#container {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#div1, #div2 {
  min-height: 0; /* Or `overflow: hidden` */
}
#div1 {
  background: red;
  flex: 0.1;
}
#inner1 {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightcoral;
}
#div2 {
  background: blue;
  flex: 0.9;
  overflow: auto;
}
#inner2 {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccccff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">
    <div id="inner1">Inner1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="inner2">Inner2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```